# Regex to validate a COMM sub string within a filename and simultaneously an .xls or .xlsx file extension

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to validate an uploaded file, that has the whole file path address, e.g. C:\Users\DOE\documents\projects\COMMERCIAL_ENTITY01.xls, C:\Users\JOHN\documents\COMM_FORENSICS.xlsx, for the substring COMM, and the file extensions .xls and .xlsx within one regex.

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds are not necessary for this. Just compose your regex as

- `COMM`
- + "anything but backslash" (`[^\]*`) to ensure the `COMM` is in the file name and not in one of the path's directory names
- + `\.xlsx?` - the extension with optional `x` at the end
- + `$` - end of string anchor:

```
COMM[^\\]*\.xlsx?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4T4YDN/1